# changing array id in an multidimensional array with another array in php

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, key

I have 2 arrays:

```
$myArray = array ( 'name' => 'Dollar', 'sign' => '$', 'format' => '1', 'decimals' => '1', 'conversion_rate' => '1.324400' );

$myArrayNew = array ( 0 => 'Name', 1 => 'Sign', 2 => 'Format', 3 => 'Decimals', 4 => 'Conversion Rate');
```

When i use

```
$combinedarrays = array_combine($myArrayNew, $myArray);
```

the output is

```
Array ( [Name] => Dollar [Sign] => $ [Format] => 1 [Decimals] => 1 [Conversion Rate] => 1.324400 )
```

That is what I need, but the problem is when my first array is multidimensional like:

```
$myArray = array( array ( 'name' => 'Dollar', 'sign' => '$', 'format' => '1', 'decimals' => '1', 'conversion_rate' => '1.324400' ),
                  array ( 'name' => 'Euro', 'sign' => '€', 'format' => '2', 'decimals' => '1', 'conversion_rate' => '1.000000' ));
```

So, how to change the keys to be like below?

```
$myArray = array( array ( 'Name' => 'Dollar', 'Sign' => '$', 'Format' => '1', 'Decimals' => '1', 'Conversion Rate' => '1.324400' ),
                  array ( 'Name' => 'Euro', 'Sign' => '€', 'Format' => '2', 'Decimals' => '1', 'Conversion Rate' => '1.000000' ));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to loop on sub arrays.

Try this:

```
$myArrayNew = array ( 0 => 'Name', 1 => 'Sign', 2 => 'Format', 3 => 'Decimals', 4 => 'Conversion Rate');

$myArray = array( array ( 'name' => 'Dollar', 'sign' => '$', 'format' => '1', 'decimals' => '1', 'conversion_rate' => '1.324400' ),
              array ( 'name' => 'Euro', 'sign' => '€', 'format' => '2', 'decimals' => '1', 'conversion_rate' => '1.000000' ));

$combinedarrays = array();
foreach($myArray as $subarr)
   $combinedarrays[] = array_combine($myArrayNew, $subarr);

print_r($combinedarrays);
```

Comment: i knew i need to loop throug the multidimensional array.